# Uniswap v2 pair before liquidity add

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation, addresses, uniswap

I have a token contract and I want to add liquidity to Uniswap (mytoken + ETH).
Before that, I would like to know the pair address in order to set it in my contract.

Is it possible to create a pair on the Uniswap Factory contract before adding liquidity to the pair?
I have seen that the Factory contract has that write function. Should I just add my token address and WETH one?

I would like an answer from someone who has used it in a similar a way, since once I setup the pair address in my contract it cannot be changed anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the pair without adding liquidity.

To do so, you need to call the `createPair()` function on the [Uniswap Factory Contract](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/4dd59067c76dea4a0e8e4bfdda41877a6b16dedc/contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol#L23). The address is [0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5c69bee701ef814a2b6a3edd4b1652cb9cc5aa6f).

Please be aware that Uniswap may upgrade to V3 at some point, at which time you would likely want to be able to upgrade your contract.